# What the exactly meaning of "as" is in the sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

In the following sentence:

> In algorithm analysis, we focus on the growth rate of the running time **as** a function of the input size n, taking a "big-picture" approach.

What's exactly meaning of **as**? Can I replace it with **in** or **of** or **when**?

Comment: *As* means "in the role/function of". The sentence says that when you're analyzing algorithms, you're concerned with the rate at which the running time changes for different input sizes *n*.

Comment: I am not an native English speaker, so I couldn't tell whether the way of author's expression is natural/good or not. Though I generally know the main meaning, I can't translate it to our language and feel bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of "as" in the sentence is optimal. Just for the sake of the explanation, a close synonym is "like", or "in the form of". Mathematically, it would be written:

> GrowthRate = f(n)

where f is to be defined / found as a result of the algorithm analysis.